# ¿Solución en SQL SERVER? "Error converting data type varchar to bigint" en CTE

Tags: sql-server

Buen día estimados se me ha encomendado que a números de transacciones que se repiten debo sumarles un uno para que estas sean unicas en este caso tengo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
Create table #TransaccionesReportar(
CodigoCorrelativo varchar(16),
OtroCampo int
);
GO
INSERT INTO #TransaccionesReportar (CodigoCorrelativo, OtroCampo)
VALUES 
('2019120101540800',1),
('2019120101540800',2),
('2019120201490300',3),
('2019120201490300',4),
('2019120201490300',5);
GO
;WITH CTE
AS (SELECT CodigoCorrelativo + 
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CodigoCorrelativo
        ORDER BY CodigoCorrelativo)-1) AS NuevoCodigo,
        CodigoCorrelativo
        FROM #TransaccionesReportar)
UPDATE Cte Set CodigoCorrelativo = NuevoCodigo FROM CTE;
GO
SELECT * FROM #TransaccionesReportar
DROP TABLE #TransaccionesReportar
```

```
-------------------------------RESULTADO---------------
CodigoCorrelativo   OtroCampo
2019120101540800       1
2019120101540801       2
2019120201490300       3
2019120201490301       4
2019120201490302       5
```

En el código anterior me funciona porque el numero de transacción es numérico, sin embargo hay transacciones que llevan letras en medio de los números como las siguientes:

```
Create table #TransaccionesReportar(
CodigoCorrelativo varchar(16),
OtroCampo int
);
GO
INSERT INTO #TransaccionesReportar (CodigoCorrelativo, OtroCampo)
VALUES 
('201912010A540800',1),
('201912010A540800',2),
('20191202AF490300',3),
('20191202AF490300',4),
('20191202AF490300',5);
GO
;WITH CTE
AS (SELECT CodigoCorrelativo + 
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CodigoCorrelativo
        ORDER BY CodigoCorrelativo)-1) AS NuevoCodigo,
        CodigoCorrelativo
        FROM #TransaccionesReportar)
UPDATE Cte Set CodigoCorrelativo = NuevoCodigo FROM CTE;
GO
SELECT * FROM #TransaccionesReportar
DROP TABLE #TransaccionesReportar
```

Al ejecutar el segundo ejemplo me da el siguiente error:

```
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
```

¿Alguien me podría apoyar con este caso?, muchísimas gracias de Antemano

Comment: Revisa la respuesta que te dejé en tu pregunta anterior.

Comment: Opta por cambiar la longitud del tipo de datos, es decir varchar(16) por varchar(18). Me cuentas que sucede!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes una letra en medio, puedes variar el código así:

```
;WITH CTE
AS (SELECT 
RIGHT(CodigoCorrelativo,4) + 
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CodigoCorrelativo
ORDER BY CodigoCorrelativo)-1)  AS NuevoCodigo,
CodigoCorrelativo
FROM TransaccionesReportar)
UPDATE CTE set CodigoCorrelativo = 
    LEFT(CodigoCorrelativo,LEN(CODIGOCORRELATIVO)-4) --    ParteIzquierda
    + 
    case 
        when len(NuevoCodigo) < 4 then RIGHT('0000' +  CAST(NUEVOCODIGO AS varchar(4)),4)
    ELSE CAST(NUEVOCODIGO AS varchar(4)) END 
    from cte;
GO
SELECT * FROM TransaccionesReportar
```

Básicamente el código varía en que recogemos, por partes el viejo código, solo utilizando los 4 últimos dígitos como parte entera para sumar.

Resultados

[image: Resultados]

Comment: Excelente bro los ejemplos que me has dado han sido espectaculares con este ultimo ya esta resuelto muchísimas gracias.